# PyTorch RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, runtime-error, convolution

I'm a college student just getting into Deep Learning, trying to create my first backward propagated model.

However, I keep getting the *"Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed."* runtime error.

I have seen many others asking the same question here, but their sample code is often too advanced for me, and I don't understand the answers.
I have already tried adding `convtraining.zero_grad()` and `loss.sum().backward(retain_graph = True)`. Neither seem to work.

My own code is the following:

```
# Import torch.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Define a sample image.
image = torch.tensor([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype = torch.float).reshape(1,1,5,5)

# Define a sample kernel.
kernel = torch.tensor([[0,-1, 0],
                       [-1, 1, -1],
                       [0,-1, 0]], dtype = torch.float).reshape(1,1,3,3)

# Define a convolution layer with the TRUE kernel weights assigned.
convolution = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), bias=False)
convolution.weight = nn.Parameter(kernel)
# Define another convolution without kernel weights to PREDICT them.
convtraining = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), bias=False)

# Run the first layer.
output_true = convolution(image)
# Reshape its output to make it suitable for comparison.
output_true = output_true.reshape((1, 1, 3, 3))

# Run the second model 5 times.
for i in range(5):
    output_prediction = convtraining(image)
    # Calculate the loss by squaring the error.
    loss = (output_prediction - output_true) ** 2
    convtraining.zero_grad()
    # Backward propagation.
    loss.sum().backward()
    # Adjust the kernel weights.
    convtraining.weight.data[:] -= 3e-2 * convtraining.weight.grad
    print(loss)
```

The strange thing is it worked before and I don't know what changed. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have already stated that using `retain_graph=True` didn't work but when I tried your exact code by just adding `retain_graph=True` it worked fine. I'm adding inside of for loop to below.

```
for i in range(5):
    output_prediction = convtraining(image)
    # Calculate the loss by squaring the error.
    loss = (output_prediction - output_true) ** 2
    convtraining.zero_grad()
    # Backward propagation.
    loss.sum().backward(retain_graph=True)

    # Adjust the kernel weights.
    convtraining.weight.data[:] -= 3e-2 * convtraining.weight.grad
    print(loss)
```

Weights of `convtraining` become this:

```
Parameter containing:
tensor([[[[-0.2317, -0.6439, -0.5469],
          [-0.6850,  0.1293, -0.4237],
          [-0.1236, -0.3529,  0.0662]]]], requires_grad=True)
```

I also checked code in debug mode line by line. It was giving reported error in second epoch but it is gone after adding `retain_graph=True`. If executing code is whole problem this seems working.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `backward()`, multiple successive calculations are done (like derivations). The intermediary results from those calculations are not kept in memory (they are deleted). Only the final results are kept for you to use.

Unfortunately, running another pass of backward propagation requires those intermediary results from the previous backward passes. In order to ensure that those needed results are kept for when you want to run another backward pass, you use `retain_graph=True` by doing :

```
loss.sum().backward(retain_graph=True)
```

instead of

```
loss.sum().backward()
```

So let's say that you want to do 3 backward passes, you do this :

```
loss.sum().backward(retain_graph=True)
loss.sum().backward(retain_graph=True)
loss.sum().backward()
```

Your code is working normally after adding `retain_graph=True` in the loop and adding an extra step at the end without `retain_graph=True`.